# Too many characters in character literal error

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a stylish text app but on some places I'm getting an error ("Too many characters in character literal"). I am  writing only one letter but when I paste it converts into many letters like this: "\uD83C\uDD89" and the original letter is "".

Please tell me how to write this in a correct way.

```
for (int charOne = 0; charOne <= strBld.length() - 1; charOne++) {
                    char a = strBld.charAt(charOne);
                    char newCh = getSpecialCharEighth(a);
                    strBld.setCharAt(charOne, newCh);

                }
```

```
private char getSpecialCharEighth(char a) {
        char ch = a;

    if (ch == 'Z' || ch == 'z') {
    ch = '\uD83C\uDD89';
    }

  return ch;
}
```

Comment: It is displayed as one "character" but in the background it consists of 2 characters, meaning you can't use the `char` type for this

Answer (score 3):

A Java `char` stores a 16-bit value, i.e. can store 65536 different values. There are currently 137929 characters in Unicode (12.1).

To handle this, Java strings are stored in UTF-16, which is a 16-bit encoding. Most Unicode characters, known as code points, are stored in a single 16-bit value. Some are stored in a pair of 16-bit values, known as surrogate pairs.

This means that a Unicode character may be stored as 2 `char` "characters" in Java, which means that if you want your code to have full Unicode character support, you can't store a Unicode character in a single `char` value.

They can be stored in an `int` variable, where the value is then referred to as a *code point* in Java. It is however often easier to store them as a `String`.

In your case, you seem to be replacing Unicode characters, so a regex replacement call might be better, e.g.

```java
s = s.replaceAll("[Zz]", "\uD83C\uDD89");

// Or like this if source file is UTF-8
s = s.replaceAll("[Zz]", "");
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep a method for determining the replacement value, you could do this:

```java
s = Pattern.compile(".").matcher(s).replaceAll​(mr -> getSpecialCharEighth(mr.group()));
```

```java
private static String getSpecialCharEighth(String s) {
    int cp = s.codePointAt(0);
    if (cp >= 'A' && cp <= 'Z')
        return Character.toString​(cp - 'A' + 0x1f170); // "" - ""
    if (cp >= 'a' && cp <= 'z')
        return Character.toString​(cp - 'a' + 0x1f170); // "" - ""
    return s;
}
```

<sup>*Note: `replaceAll​(replacer)` is Java 9+ and  `Character.toString(codePoint)` is Java 11+.*</sup>

---

**UPDATE 2**

Since question is tagged `android`, Java 9 and Java 11 APIs are not available, so here is Java 7+ solution.

```java
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(s.length() + 16);
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".").matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(buf, getSpecialCharEighth(m.group()));
s = m.appendTail(buf).toString();
```

```java
private static String getSpecialCharEighth(String s) {
    int cp = s.codePointAt(0);
    if (cp >= 'A' && cp <= 'Z')
        return new String(new int[] { cp - 'A' + 0x1f170 }, 0, 1);
    if (cp >= 'a' && cp <= 'z')
        return new String(new int[] { cp - 'a' + 0x1f170 }, 0, 1);
    return s;
}
```

*Result with `s = "Hello World!"`*

```
 !
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with char data type. Use String instead.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

> **char**: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Comment: You can't do *what* with a `char` data type? You should explain why it's a problem.

Comment: Ok... explanation added