# To many characters in character literal (surrogate characters)

Tags: java, android, char

I'm facing this error

> To many caracters in character literal.

I know a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737816/too-many-characters-in-character-literal-error) question was already answered. Plz help me with this because that answer does not work for me.

Here is my code

```java
case 1:

        for (int charOne = 0; charOne <= strBld.length() - 1; charOne++) {
                char a = strBld.charAt(charOne);
                char newCh = getCharOne(a);
                strBld.setCharAt(charOne, newCh);
        }

        break;
```

This is working fine.

```
    private char getCharOne(char a){
        char ch = a;
    
        if (ch == 'B' || ch == 'b') {
            ch = '๒';
        }

        return ch;

    }
```

But now I want to use this (surrogate characters)

when i paste it converts into    \uD83C\uDD50  this format and an error shown To many characters in character literal

```
    private char getCharOne(char a){
        char ch = a;
        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'a') {
            ch = '\uD83C\uDD50';
        }

        return ch;
    }
```

Comment: a char can only be a single char, if you want a variable with several chars, create a String

Comment: @Stultuske  please add more details.

Comment: either use a char array or string to save mutiple char

Comment: '\uD83C\uDD50'  -> these are several chars. a char -> the type says it itself, can only contain one

Comment: What do you want to have?@Marsad Maqsood

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin simple I want to get output 

Comment: and I don't know how to do this

Comment: Why don't you write ch = 'A' instead of ch = '\uD83C\uDD50'? It will work

Comment: I am trying to convert A into  (stylish text)

Comment: \uD83C\uDD50 has come from where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209693/discussion-between-marsad-maqsood-and-mohammadmoeingolchin).

Comment: Don't you check my answer as correct? If you have problem yet, ask another question@Marsad Maqsood

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209737/discussion-between-mohammadmoeingolchin-and-marsad-maqsood).

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin ok

Comment: The problem is your first representation is a single character and you want to replace it with two characters. You cannot replace it with `StringBuilder.setCharAt`. You could use StringBuilder.insert to add the extra character. Your method also needs to return a char[] instead of a char.

Comment: `char ch = a;` why would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write more than one character in ' '. You have defined ch as character so
you can't give string to it
You should define another variable as string and give \uD83C\uDD50 to it.
for example:

```
var a:String
a="\uD83C\uDD50"
```